# SDK and AVD Manager will not run after uninstalling the ADT plugin

Tags: android

Windows XP x32

After uninstalling the Eclipse ADT plugin, the Android SDK and AVD managers will not run. A command prompt window pops up, but closes and nothing happens. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to uninstall the ADT plugin? That's the basis from which the SDK and AVD managers run from. Reinstall it if you want to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse ADT plugin is used to run the **Android SDK** and **AVD managers** in Eclipse. So why do you want to uninstall it? 
If u dont want to use Eclipse for your programming, then the plugin is not required, just install using th steps given here-
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you let Eclipse delete something you shouldn't have.  Re-install the SDK and I bet they'll work again.